# gmpy2.div gives TypeError: div() argument types not supported

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I'm trying to minimize a function with basin-hopping algorithm in sci-py. Here is my code:

```
from math import *
import time
import gmpy2
from gmpy2 import mpz
from gmpy2 import mpq,mpfr,mpc
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS"}


s=mpz('2')
x0=[153000]
b = mpfr('6097781399')
estimator1=gmpy2.div(x0, s)-gmpy2.sqrt(((pow(x0,s)/4)-b))
estimator2=gmpy2.div(x0, s)+gmpy2.sqrt(((pow(x0,s)/4)-b))

c=mpfr(estimator1)
d=mpfr(estimator2)
e=mpz(b)

func = lambda x: abs((c*d)-e)

ret = basinhopping(func, x0, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
niter=400)
print("global minimum: x = %.4f, f(x0) = %.4f" % (ret.x, ret.fun))
```

the full error reads

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "anneal.py", line 14, in  estimator1=gmpy2.div(x0, s)-gmpy2.sqrt(((pow(x0,s)/4)-b)) TypeError: div() argument types not supported

What I'm basically trying to achieve is minimizing `abs((c*d)-e)`, however I get an error as: `TypeError: div() argument types not supported`. I have Googled about this error and perhaps the cause of this is a type mismatch between a variable and a list. So my question is how should I re-formulate `estimator1` and `estimator2` to be able to pass it into basin-hopping minimizer.

Edit:

Corrected code now reads (also removed unnecessary imports):

```
from math import *
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "BFGS"}
def f(x):

    b = 6097781399
    estimator1=(x/2)-sqrt(abs((pow(x,2)/4)-b))
    estimator2=(x/2)+sqrt(abs((pow(x,2)/4)-b))
    return abs((estimator1*estimator2)-b)

x = 110000
ret = basinhopping(f, x, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs,
niter=2000)
print("global minimum: x = %.4f, f(x0) = %.4f" % (ret.x, ret.fun))
```

Comment: can you post the full error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\msalperen\Desktop\anneal.py", line 14, in <module>
    estimator1=gmpy2.div(x0, s)-gmpy2.sqrt(((pow(x0,s)/4)-b))
TypeError: div() argument types not supported

Comment: I think the problem is that you're passing in a python `list` into `gmpy2.div`. The `C` code checks for int, rational, real and complex and if none of those fits it throws the error you mentioned. Have you tried passing in `x0` as an `int`?

Comment: I have removed the brackets around x0 and this time I get:
"TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

Comment: ok, now you're getting an error from `numpy` not from `gmpy2` anymore. Have you checked that you can even use the `mpz` data type in `scipy` functions? I'd be surprised if that just works

Comment: I have removed all the references to gmpy, mpz and mpfr; and the formulae now looks like : estimator1=(x0/2)-sqrt(abs((pow(x0,2)/4)-b)) and estimator2=(x0/2)+sqrt(abs((pow(x0,2)/4)-b)). This returns a result but it always returns the original(predefiined) x0 as the global minimum. I think I should read more about scipy documentation on this issue, but at least I got rid of errors. Any suggestions beyond this, on how to work on large numbers together with scipy and how to get acceptable global minima are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're passing in a python `list` into `gmpy2.div`. The `C` code checks for `int`, `rational`, `real` and `complex` and if none of those fits it throws the error you mentioned. Try passing in `x0` as an int.

Further I don't think `scipy` will be too happy about the `mpz(2)` you're passing in, `scipy` usually works with either python `lists`, `scipy.sparse` matrices or dense `numpy.ndarray`s.

In terms of handling large numbers in python, the `int`s are unbounded (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). NumPy is also a good place to look when you need numerically stable operations, numpy has it's own type system with 64bit `float`s and `int`s and 128 bit complex numbers.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Comment: I have defined my variables in a function and initial value outside that function. Now it seems to work (I have inserted an updated code above for further reference). Thanks.